# Rails item feed of distinct items shared by users followed by the current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-postgresql

So I'm trying to make a feed of items in which the items are distinct, and each item can be shared by many users.  My data model is:

User: has_many :postings, has_many :products, :through => :postings

Product has_many :postings, has_many :users, :through :postings

Posting belongs_to :user, belongs_to :product

So I'm trying to find a windowable (offset,limit) list of unique products, and also get the user data (or at least one field) so that I don't have to query it in the views.  Here is the query I'm running now:

```
 def feed_items(offset, limit)
  ids = followed_users.map(&:id)
  ids.push id
  all_rows_sql = Posting.where("user_id IN (#{ids.join(',')})").order("created_at DESC").select("product_id, row_number() over (partition by product_id) as row_number").to_sql
  sql = "SELECT product_id FROM(#{all_rows_sql}) as rows where row_number = 1 OFFSET #{offset} LIMIT #{limit}"
  postings = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
  product_ids = []
  postings.each {|p| product_ids.push p['product_id'].to_i}
  products = Product.find product_ids
  orderedProducts = []
  for product in products
    orderedProducts[product_ids.index(product.id)] = product
  end
  orderedProducts
end
```

This gets the list of products in a reasonable time, but in my views I have to say product.users.each to show the list of users beneath the item.  This results in a massive amount of queries, and also hitting the db from views, both of which are a problem.  Does anyone have some insight on how to get the user id at the same time as the product ids?

Thanks